# Rake cannot load sqlite3 file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, sqlite

I am new to Ruby on Rails and am simply trying to setup a sample application by following a getting started guide. I am installing Rails on a Mac OS X Mountain Lion. I get rails working where I can run the default getting started application. When I try to run the rake db:create command, however, I am getting the following message:

rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native

I know there are a bunch of questions asked and answered regarding this but none of the suggestions already identified have been able to help.

Please let me know what I can do to get this working.

Thanks
Cameron

Comment: did you run the `bundle install` command? if you did? do you have the `gem sqlite3` directive in your Gemfile?

Comment: Yes. I ran the bundle install and also verified that the gem sqlite3 directive is in my Gemfile. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Try: bundle exec rake db:create

Comment: I got the same error after running that command.

Comment: are you using rvm or rbenv? - show us the output of `ruby -v`, `which ruby`, 'gem list'